# Prove that $H$ is a normal subgroup in the finite group $G=\langle S\rangle $ iff $sHs^{-1}$ $\subseteq H$ for all $s\in S$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let H be a subgroup in a group $G$. If $G$ is generated by a set $S$, so $G=\langle S\rangle $, prove that $H$ is a normal subgroup in $G$ iff $sHs^{-1}$ $\subseteq H$ for all $s\in S$.

Note with the question: Results of this sort are useful because it is easier to check an algebraic property for a small set of generators than to prove it holds for all elements of G.

Hi, the forward direction is quite straightforward but I will be really grateful if somebody can help me with the reverse direction. Thanks!

Comment: What about improving your title?

Comment: is it better now?

Comment: Yes, thanks, I think that helps for reference etc. It would be even better with $G=\langle S\rangle$ instead of $G$.

Comment: can u help me with the solution?

Comment: See Serkan's answer and the comments. Where did you get the question? Are you sure you gave the exact assumptions? Isn't $G$, or just  $H$, finite?

Comment: the question is a practice problem from my professor and it doesn't say anything about G or H being finite.

Comment: Maybe your professor assumed in some moment that groups would be finite in that problem set? People tend to do that.

Comment: The best way to make this correct is to assume also that $s^{-1}Hs \le H$ for all $s \in S$ (which is true if all elements of $S$ have finite order, so in particular if $G$ is finite).

Answer (score 3):

It seems this is wrong. The problem is that $S$ does not need to be closed under inverses.

Let $N = \oplus_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_2$ and let $K = \langle g \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}$ act on $N$ by $g \mapsto$ shifting right by 1 unit. Form the semidirect product $G = N \rtimes K$. Let $M$ be the subgroup of $N$ consisting of sequences with 0 entries in negative coordinates. Let $S = N \cup \{g\}$. Then $S$ generates $G$ and fixes $M$.
But $M$ is not normal in $G$.

Comment: Maybe we need *finite* in the above?

Comment: It suspected so. Note $\subseteq$ is enough, though.

Comment: Well-spotted. A simpler example (to my mind): let $G$ be the free group generated by $a$ and $b$, $H$ the group generated by the union of all conjugates of $\langle a\rangle$ by the free monoid generated by $a$ and $b$, and $S=\{a,b\}$. @PeterTamaroff No, it already is $\subseteq$ as it stands. Either: stipulate $G$ is finite, that $S$ is closed under inverses, or replace $\subseteq$ with $=$ (equivalently, stipulate that $H$ does not properly contain any conjugate).

Comment: @Serkan I meant that *if* $G$ is finite, then $\subseteq$ is enough. I might have rushed my thought, though.

Comment: @Serkan, of course we can just say in more generality that *if* $G$ is finitely generated and $H$ is stable under conjugation by $s\in S$, then the theorem follows. I didn't look at the case where $H$ is fixed under conjugation, however.

Comment: @Serkan: The $H$ I described satisfies $s^{-1}Hs\subseteq H$ for all $s$ in the free monoid generated by $a$ and $b$ (i.e. the set of all words with positive powers of $a$ and $b$), since it satisfies it for $s=a$ and $s=b$. We assume conjugation is defined by $x^g:=g^{-1}xg$. Under this convention, for every word in $H$, the first power of $b$ appearing in said word is a *negative* power. So $a\in H$ but $bab^{-1}\not\in H$, hence $H$ is not normal (which is by design, just like with your example), even though $H$ is closed under conjugation by the generating set $S$.

Comment: Hi, so can we prove that H is normal?

Comment: so can you please write down the proof if G is finite? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just collecting some ideas from the long thread:

The statement IS true if we have $sHs^{-1} = H$ for all $s \in S$.

Proof: Consider $N_G(H) = \{g \in G \mid gHg^{-1} = H\}$, this is called the normalizer of $H$ in $G$. You can prove (for arbitrary $G$ and $H$) that this is a subgroup of $G$. In our case, our assumption is that $S \subseteq N_G(H)$, and so $\langle S \rangle \subseteq N_G(H)$, and so $N_G(H) = G$. This implies $H$ is normal in $G$.

Now, suppose we only know that $sHs^{-1} \subseteq H$. We can finish the proof if:

$\bullet$ $G$ is finite: In this case, $H$ is finite, and $sHs^{-1}$ has the same number of elements as $H$, so we must have $sHs^{-1} = H$.

$\bullet$ $S$ contains inverses: In this case, for all $s \in S$ we have $sHs^{-1} \subseteq H$ and $(s^{-1})H(s^{-1})^{-1} = s^{-1}Hs \subseteq H$. Together, these imply that $sHs^{-1} = H$.

As others have shown, the statement is NOT true as you have written it.

Comment: i edited it, if G is finite, does your proof still work?

Comment: Yes: See the first bullet point.

Answer (score 0):

Write down an arbitrary element in $G$ in terms of the generating set.  See what happens when you apply the element to $H$ by conjugation.

Comment: can you please write out what you mean by that? thanks!